# Solution for forced harmonic motion with non-constant frequency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, integration, differential-equations, greens-functions

Is there any integral form of the solution for the equation below?
$$
\ddot{y}+\omega^2(t) y = f(t)
$$
where it's basically the equation for forced harmonic motion with non-constant frequency.
If $\omega$ is constant, I know the general solution can be written as a convolution,
$$
y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-\tau) h(\tau)\ d\tau
$$
where $$h(t)=H(t)\sin(\omega t)/\omega$$ is the impulse response function with $H(\cdot)$ being the Heaviside function.
Is there a similar form that solves the first equation above?

Comment: No (at least not in terms of elementary functions); and to see the kinds of crazy behavior you can get with even an (apparently) simple $\omega^2(t)$, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function.